# Asynchronous socket + waitone()

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

Let's start with some code:

```
class InternetConnector
{
    private struct ConnectionData
    {
        public Action<Socket> SuccessHandler { get; set; }
        public ClientStateObject clientObj { get; set; }
        public Action<Exception> ErrorHandler { get; set; }
        public Socket Socket { get; set; }
    }
    public static ManualResetEvent processingDone = new ManualResetEvent( false );
    public static ConcurrentQueue<string> messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    public bool ReceiveMessage(Action<Socket> successHandler, Action<Exception> errorHandler)
    {
        ClientStateObject obj = new ClientStateObject();
        obj.server = client;
        var connectionData = new ConnectionData
        {
            ErrorHandler = errorHandler,
            SuccessHandler = successHandler,
            Socket = client,
            clientObj = obj
        };
        if (Connected)
        {
            client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
            receive = true;
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
        }
        return receive;
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ConnectionData connectionData = new ConnectionData();
        bool complete = false;
        try
        {
            connectionData = (ConnectionData)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = connectionData.Socket;
            int num = client.EndReceive(ar);
            {
                connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, num));
                string response = connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.ToString();
                string[] msgs = response.Split('&');
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string sts = msgs[i];
                    messages.Enqueue(sts + "&" );
                }
                receiveDone.Set();
                if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
                {
                    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
                    processingDone.WaitOne();
                    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (connectionData.ErrorHandler != null)
                connectionData.ErrorHandler(e);
        }
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private InternetConnector client = new InternetConnector();
    private bool isRunning = false;

    private void AsyncSuccessHandler(Socket socket)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action( () => AsyncSuccessHandler( socket ) ));
            return;
        }
        if (InternetConnector.messages.Count() == 0)
        {
            status.Text = "Signals Receiver: Connected";
            status.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            isRunning = true;
            client.ReceiveMessage(AsyncSuccessHandler, AsyncErrorHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            GUIChangeOnConnection();
            InternetConnector.processingDone.Set();
        }
    }

    private void GUIChangeOnConnection()
    {
            for( int i = 0; i < InternetConnector.messages.Count; i++ )
            {
                string message;
                InternetConnector.messages.TryDequeue( out message );
// process the message
            }
    }
 }
```

Now the problem.

Everything works fine. Reading from the socket is happening. However the call `processingDone.WaitOne();` which should block the callback indefinitely until the call to `processingDone.Set();` returns too early.

I verified it by setting the breakpoint at the end of the `GUIChangeOnConnection();` - function closing bracket line. It hits the breakpoint and looking at the `InternetConnector.messages` I see that the queue is not empty, which means that the for loop did not finish.
And the second time this breakpoint is hit the number of messages in the queue is sky-rocketing.

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe my design is incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: first thing I see, You don't have to do `ConnectionData connectionData = new ConnectionData()` since you are assigning it in the try clause. So you can safely remove `= new ConnectionData();`

Comment: Could you please provide more client code? Is `AsyncSuccessHandler` method called first time by `Socket.BeginConnect`?

Comment: Why are you doing an asynchronous receive since you're blocking until the callback is done, making the whole operation synchronous?

Comment: @Default, Wouldn't I get the compiler error: "Using uninitialized variable"?

Comment: @Serge, Yes, it is called from BeginConnect(). Why?

Comment: @JulienLebosquain, because I want the GUI to be responsive no matter what. And in case of synchronous call to connect, the GUI will be put on hold.

Comment: @Igor that's true! I missed it in the catch clause. Ignore first statement :)